# Best practice for extracting Razor-embedded JavaScript code into a separate file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a large `.cshtml` file that contains a lot of inline JavaScript. To me the ability to do something like this is very useful:

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
        type: "post",
        data: $form.serialize()
    });
}
```

However as the code size grows, Intellisense is getting extremely slow and I would like to extract my JavaScript code into a separate `.js`. file. I know there is [RazorJS](http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files) but I prefer not to use that in my project.

Should I extract these Razor expressions into JavaScript variables, extract the remaining code into a separate file and then reference the values from there instead? What's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some of this with unobtrusive JS techniques, e.g. putting the action on the form (even if you don't actually submit the form).

**View**

```html
<!-- Of course, you would probably use Html.BeginForm() here -->
<form action="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" id="form1"></form>
```

**Script File**

```
function submitForm() {

    // you can abstract this further if you don't like having IDs 
    // hardcoded (I don't). Data attributes can help with this.
    var form = $("#form1");

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: "post",
        data: form.serialize()
    });
}
```

> However as the code size grows, Intellisense is getting extremely slow
>   and I would like to extract my JavaScript code into a separate .js.
>   file.

You perform more extensive abstraction by adding `data-*` attributes to relevant elements. While this is very clean, it can also make your code unduly complex.

If you have hundreds of lines of JavaScript, definitely spend the time to extract it. If you only have a few dozen lines of pure "plumbing" code, I'd try to find out why Intellisense is slow.

Comment: My Razor codes are mostly calls to `@Url.Content` and `@Url.Action` but I really doubt is creating dummy form tags to store actions a good practice at all?

Comment: Also I need to support IE8 users...Are `data-*` attributes supported by IE8?

Comment: Yes, IE8 is supported. A form is a semantically valid container for form elements; I'm not suggesting to create form elements *solely* to store attributes; just to add attributes to your existing forms.

Answer (score 1):

There is another technique to do what you want to do, but I'm not sure it is ideal.

Simply create a partial view (.cshtml), only containing a `<script></script>` element, and inside place the js you are willing to extract.

You can then leave your Html helpers just like they were in your JS, and simply use the Html.Partial helper in the original page, to display your newly created partial view with your JS code.

As your file IS a cshtml file, razor will parse it, as it is already doing it in your current page.